# How can I specify a custom domain with googleyolo?

Tags: google-identity

With the traditional OAuth API, I can specify the `?hd=<domain>` parameter to limit logins to specific G Suite domains. I'm unable to find a way to do this with the googleyolo auto sign-in API.

Is this supported or am I just not able to use the API at this time?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the product manager at Google for this library. This is a good feature request and we have it on the roadmap but no timeline yet. I'll update this answer when it's available, but we've got a ton of great feedback and requests from developers around this library so it might be some time to work through the backlog.